# NPN - PNP Vbe Matched Pairs.. Can I use 2N3906 with 2SC945

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp

I am trying to build the following exponential converter circuit from the Thomas Henry "Making Music with the 3080 OTA" document.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQdY0o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I understand from his text that this circuit may be ok for VCAs and VCFs but isn't ideal for tuning VCOs unless you can find an NPN-PNP Matched pair, which is very difficult to do.  I'm not quite yet at the skill level to understand the matched pair expo converters using a differential amplifier setup of two matched PNP or NPN transistors, but I do understand this circuit and would like to see if I can use it for a simple VCO of about 4 octaves before I continue studying the more standard matched pair expo converters.

**Question:** Can I use two different kinds of NPN/PNPs to match, such as a 2N3906 and a 2SC945, or would the two transistors have to be complements of the same kind like the 2N3906-2N3904?  I managed to find a 2N3906 and 2SC945 who's Vbe deltas are just about 2mV. Can I use those in this circuit?

Comment: Try using a sim tool and altering the ambient temperature to see what happens to VCO frequency stability.

Comment: Huh, didn't even know Sim tools could do that.  I will try this